# How does TeamCity calculate remaining build time

Tags: teamcity

I am using TeamCity for Continuous Integration, and one Linux server is taking about an hour longer for builds after moving it to a new Virtual host.  I thought it might be the CIFS mount acting up so I remounted it which seems to have resolved the long read write times, but after kicking off a build, it says the remaining time which is still an hour longer than it should be.  Is that number based on the last build or are there some metrics being taken and the number is calculated via some algorithm? TeamCity Version 7.0, build server is Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I doubt this can be answered without diving into the source code. Are you willing to, @gregg?

Comment: Seems to me that TeamCity just adds up the last builds and makes a guess from that.  It might also use the CPU value it calculates for each agent ( you can see it under the agent tab ).  Of course I'm just guessing.

Comment: Is there any way to see the history of a CPU benchmark for an agent?  Like if it was higher 2 months ago, can I check that somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is computed statistically, it will auto-correct after some builds.